# what is the main purpose technically speaking about the abstraction in programming using DI, Interfaces, and Abstract Classes?

Tags: dependency-injection, abstraction

I viewed a couple of answers online regarding Abstractions, Abstract Classes, Interface's, DI, and Loose coupling. But none of these answers are answering my question. I grouped these topics because they are related to achieving abstractions. Got a good understanding of the mentioned topics, but yet not fully understand them in detail and how they related to each other.

Generally speaking, interfaces are used to make classes loosely coupled. Thus define a set of functions and fields to be implemented. The idea of making Loosely Coupled classes is that will need to remove dependency over several classes.

For instance, if we make a change to one of these classes then we do not need to change other places making code maintainable. The only good example I can think of to use loosely coupling is through DI. So when we say interfaces make classes loosely coupled do we mean by passing an interface as a dependency?

"Please continue reading will further clarify".

A question here is if we are going to use DI and pass interfaces as dependencies then why not pass a class as a dependency instead? maybe I will need further clarification about Interfaces before answering the previous question. I will further explain.

The main idea of interfaces is to establish contact with classes that going to implement the interface meaning we are going to need to define functions and fields to enforce to implement them. but still, the idea of interfaces as a contract is not yet clear because if we enforce a developer to implement an interface called a server that has methods to turn on and off the server but the developer forgot to turn off the server programmatically then what is the point of this contract?

Further, my understanding is that this all falls under the concept of abstraction which means we do not need to worry about details but an abstraction. Does that not mean when building an application we first need to create classes/structures without code such as using UML?

Further, why would we use an abstract class over interfaces where an abstract class has similarities to an interface such as defining a function but without a body?

Coming back to Interfaces and DI we can inject interfaces as a dependency but why? Can we not inject a class it self? is it not easier to use classes as a dependency? where we can access all functions or this is not the idea of interface Can sombody help with this. I only understand one use case on why we should use DI. Example:

```
//Class1 
//Class1 Con
Public Class1 Con(){
 Class2 class2 = new Class2(1,1,1)
}
```

The above example is not maintainable because if we add a new parameter to `Class2` then we need to modify it elsewhere. but if we use DI Injection then we won't are there any other reasons.

Also, DI can be useful to create one instance and use that instance across the whole application. Does that save some memory by not creating multiple instances? or saving time connecting to DI?

The question should we use abstractions at the very early coding stage where we create classes without code?

Further, do we use interfaces to make the developer aware that they need to implement a certain set of functions? But why?

Do I predict that we need to use an interface by creating UML diagrams to see if there would be different classes to use an interface with similar functionalities

"Can we not just create a superclass and override methods"

Can somebody explain when to use superclass and override methods over interfaces and provide an implementation?

Also, when to pass an interface as a dependency? And when to pass a class as a dependency? One advantage I can think of when using interfaces is polymorphism where we can make an interface of any implemented types and then access the interface type function; polymorphism. Example:

```
Class1 class = new Interface1();
```

Can this be possible?

Comment: The format of your question is unsuited for Stack Overflow, because there are a dozen of questions here. That makes it impossible to give a concise answer. I don't even know where to begin. There are many books written about the topic of DI, design patterns, and loose coupling in general. Just pick one; they will all explain the rational behind DI and interfaces. For instance, read with the freely available [chapter 1](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1) of [my book](https://cuttingedge.it/book) on DI.

Comment: @Steven okay will do that. Just through its all one question under the concept of abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line is we would like always to make our class's loosely coupled. Meaning that decouple class's to achieve maintainable. Thus, loosely coupled classes provider's late binding, extensibility, maintainability and easy testing. May refer to reference 1. We use interface's to make class's loosely coupled as well. but before answering how. we need to understand interface's why we use them and how they are different to abstract class's. Interface's are mainly used as contract meaning that when we create multiple class's sharing same behaviour but with different implementation then we use interface's. Thus, its a set of infrastructure to tell developer's what method's to implement. interface's only includes functions, fields signature with no implementation.

How we use DI to achieve loosely coupled class's is by injecting dependencies. suppose the following class's implements interface called Database:

```
     public interface Database
    {
        void Save();
    }

   class SqlServer : Database
    {
        public void Save()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving...");
        }
    }
    class Oracle : Database
    {
        public void Save()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Saving...");
        }
    }
```

Then we can easily inject dependencies as follows:

```
   class Library
    {
        //private Database _SqlServer;
        private Database _Oracle;

        public Student(IDAL _SqlServer)
        {
            this._SqlServer = _SqlServer;
        }
        public void SaveBoo()
        {
            _SqlServer.Save();
        }
    }
```

Using the above approach we are injecting dependencies meaning that class's are now not fully tightly coupled. if any change made to `_SqlServer` we do not have to worry. To achieve full decoupled class's then use DI container Refer to reference 1.

The difference between abstract class's and interface's is that we use interface to define a contract where we use abstract if we want partial implementation. In Abstract class's you can define some method's implementation while leaving other as abstract.

You may create UML class diagrams to represent class's relationship without the need to worry about the coding side yet

As I am replying to my own question I would think it’s good to create classes and relationship I will call it classes structure then do all code later in case UML Class diagram is not going to be used. I guess this will fall under the technique/concept that is called abstraction where we do not yet worry about the details yet. So we can have an image about how is the application is structured without using UML’s.
Hope make sense

References:
(https://findnerd.com/account/#url=/list/view/Dependency-Injection-in--Net/24098/)